# Truly Global Variable in python

Tags: python, global-variables, simulation

OK so the project I am working on requires* using a truly global variable (or five) and the other questions on here have to do with cross module variables (could be helpful later just not yet).

Here is my problem: I have a program that will be running an environmental simulation and I need to set some global variables to be used and modified inside some of the functions. How would one go about doing that?

*When I say require I mean that I haven't found a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I'd probably use memcached or redis for something like this.

Comment: What does "truly global" mean if not "cross-module (like built-in) global"? You mean shared between processes? Shared between separate runs at different times? Shared between every copy of the program running on any computer in the world? Spherical, with a map projected on them?

Comment: As always it depends, but there are literally 3 cases in software development where global variable is the right answer. What exactly is preventing you from just passing the relevant data from one function to another?

Comment: What I am asking is if there is a way to make a variable accessible to all functions in one program.

Comment: Why do you believe that your program requires global variables? Sure, globals may be convenient, but they mess up modular design (and testing). You should probably be using a class to store the state parameters of your environmental simulation.

Comment: Any name defined in a Python script (aka as a module) outside of a class or function is automatically global to the module. You can also define them in functions or methods by using a [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global_stmt). Also see the FAQ [_What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?_](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) in the documentation.

Comment: what I am asking is if there is a way to to do something like the "return" command just to put a value **into** a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use and modify global variables inside functions that are spread across several modules. Put the variables in a module and import that module into your main program:

```
# globals.py
klaatu = "Once in Persia reigned a king ..."
```

```
# main_program.py
import globals

def modify_klaatu():
    print globals.klaatu
    globals.klaatu = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times."
```

Comment: Do you know if this also works when multithreading?

Comment: This doesn't work if there is another module that also imports `globals`. That module will have a separate copy of `globals`, which won't be changed by the `modify_klaatu` function, which only modifies `main_program.globals.klaatu`.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat dodgy but entirely dynamic variant of @rob's approach:

```
import types
import sys

sys.modules['myglobals'] = types.ModuleType('myglobals')
sys.modules['myglobals'].__dict__.update({'first': 'thing', 'second': 'thing'})

import myglobals
print(myglobals.first) # prints 'thing'
```

Or if you've only got one global, how about this *extremely* dodgy approach:

```
import sys
sys.modules['myglobal'] = 'thing'

import myglobal
print(myglobal) # prints 'thing'
```